# Poor audio volumes on HP (15-ax003na) with Bang & Olufsen sound - 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound

I'm experiencing very low audio output from my laptop. This surprises me based on the hardware and I was wondering whether there was anything that might be affecting it from an OS perspective? I reformatted practically straight away so didn't test the audio on Windows and therefore have nothing for comparison.

I would say that along with low volume the sound being outputted lacks any real character. It's a pretty flat sound which leads me to believe that it's not the hardware based on the brand.

```
Card: HDA Intel PCH
Chip: Realtek ALC295
```

Anyone else have this hardware or similar and experience this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix Bang and Olufsen Audio for HP laptops?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/899021/how-to-fix-bang-and-olufsen-audio-for-hp-laptops)