# How to fix Bang and Olufsen Audio for HP laptops?

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, speakers

I'm trying to install bang and olufsen drivers, or HP hd audio driver, as only 2 of the 4 speakers work and the 2 amps don't work in ubuntu

```
lspci -v | grep -i audio
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Broadwell-U Audio Controller
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller
```

The volume is terrible. Is there any way to fix this?

The speakers work perfectly on the pre-installed Windows 8.

Comment: There are no other drivers.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/873881/how-to-install-bang-and-olufsen-audio-drivers-for-hp-laptop

Comment: Can you post `amixer -c 0` and `amixer -c 1`  in your question?

Comment: @MathCubes Your link is about headphones and this question is about speakers. Most reports are headphones work great and top two speakers (powered by separate amplifier) work in Windows but not Linux.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1424600/1178898

Answer (score 3):

## Two years later it is possible!

There is a new [answer with a comment confirming it works](https://askubuntu.com/a/1120269/307523). The link is included so people are apprised of updates to this issue.

---

## Original answer

This is no longer true but left her for posterity purposes.

### It doesn't seem possible

I looked on HP website and found this:

- [How to install Bang and Olufsen Audio drivers on Ubuntu 16.04](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Audio/How-to-install-Bang-and-Olufsen-Audio-drivers-on-Ubuntu-16/td-p/6069282)

The so-called "HP Expert" there said it's like trying to put a jet engine in a car and make it fly like an AirBus A380. So not very promising. He did reference another question here in ***Ask Ubuntu***:

- [How to install Bang and Olufsen Audio drivers for HP laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873881/how-to-install-bang-and-olufsen-audio-drivers-for-hp-laptop)

...however that has no answers either.

### Do a little more digging

I did a little more digging and found this bug report:

- [HP Spectre x360 (Kabylake) just front speakers work](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=189331)

There are 91 comments posted from November 29, 2016 up to yesterday (August 12, 2017). There are various band-aid approaches people have tried. I suggest you subscribe to the bug report and keep abreast of bug fixes / work arounds.

Like your system there are two front speakers powered from motherboard and two back speakers powered by separate amplifier.

The most successful band-aid to date requires installing a windows update and rebooting into Linux. This "tricks" the amplifier to being powered on. After rebooting into Linux poking in some register configuration values is required. You can read all about it in the 91 comments but I just wanted to summarize it for you.

Hopefully someone will reverse-engineer the Windows driver for Bang & Olufsen and create one for Linux. It doesn't appear HP is willing to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I purchased a late 2017 Spectre X360, model 13-ae013dx. I was able to solve this bug consistently using HDAJackRetask under Antergos by performing the following:

- Override pin 0x14 and set it to Internal Speaker (LFE). I believe this enables the amplifier that drives the top speakers. Setting it to something other than just "Internal Speaker" is important, so that pulseaudio does not try to redirect sound to that channel.
- Override pin 0x1e and set them to "Internal Speaker".

Hit Apply Now, and voila you have sound out of all four speakers.

Config screenshot:

[image]

I'm currently running Kernel 4.20.10-arch1-1-ARCH, and I have tried absolutely everything on this thread to no avail. Hope this helps!

Comment: I have a late 2017 Spectre 15 inch and I think this worked very well for me.  Your PASTEBOARD IMAGE was very helpful!

I have to mention that the "Apply Now" failed with error that it was busy; however, applying to boot override and rebooting worked!

Comment: @armc Thank you for confirming this answer from a very old problem. I've added it to my answer so people know to come here instead.

Comment: I have HP Pavilion - 15-bc204nw. In my case this fix finally helped, bu I couldn't apply this change (resource busy), I had to use "Install boot override"

Comment: (+1) This worked for me. **However**, I had to adjust the settings for all pins to match those in the screenshot. See my answer below for details.

Comment: I used *exactly* these same settings and this solution failed for me

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: Before trying my solution below, see a (probably better) answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1424600/1178898).

---

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.4 on a HP ENVY 16-inch laptop that I purchased in August 2022. [@Juan P.'s answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1120269/1178898) worked for me. **However**, I had to use the exact same settings they had in their screenshot, and not only the ones they mentioned in the text of their answer. I've typed out these settings here in case the screenshot in their answer is no longer available.

To summarize, the steps for fixing the Bang & Olufsen speakers is as follows:

1. Open a terminal window.
2. Run `sudo apt-get install alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui`.
3. Run `hdajackretask`.
4. At the "Select a codec" drop-down list, choose `Realtek ALC245`.
5. On the right-hand side of the `hdajackretask` window, click on the checkbox "Show unconnected pins".
6. For each pin, you will either have to click the "Override" checkbox and then change the configuration using the drop-down list, or leave the pin alone if the right configuration is already set. If there is a pin ID in the table below that you do not see, skip it. Here are the configurations that you should have for each pin:

| Pin name | Pin ID | Drop-down list option |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Not connected | 0x12 | Not connected |
| Not connected | 0x13 | Not connected |
| Not connected | 0x14 | Internal speaker (LFE) |
| Not connected | 0x16 | Not connected |
| Internal Speaker | 0x17 | Internal speaker |
| Not connected | 0x18 | Not connected |
| Black Mic, Left side | 0x19 | Microphone |
| Not connected | 0x1a | Not connected |
| Not connected | 0x1b | Not connected |
| Not connected | 0x1d | Not connected |
| Not connected | 0x1e | Internal speaker |
| Black Headphone, Left side | 0x21 | Headphone |

7. Finally, click on "Install boot override" and then reboot. Sound should now work.

Comment: this didn't work for me on an HP Envy with 22.04

Comment: Hi @con, this answer is actually outdated. See this better answer instead: https://askubuntu.com/a/1424600

Answer (score 0):

Based on @robertjjoynt answer from 
*https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1648183/comments/17*

and [Mayank Sharma](https://askubuntu.com/users/616758/mayank-sharma) has written a detailed answer on [How to install Bang and Olufsen Audio drivers for HP laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873881/how-to-install-bang-and-olufsen-audio-drivers-for-hp-laptop)

follow the instructions there.