# Rear audio volume very low - Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I recently acquired an [HP Omen Obelisk](https://store.hp.com/us/en/mdp/desktops/omen-875?jumpid=cp_r12135_us/en/psg/gaming_omen/desktops/omen-obelisk-shop#!&tab=vao)

Installed ubuntu 19.04 on another hard drive and am able to login and most things work normally.

This machine has two audio jacks. One in front and one in back. For some reason by default the rear audio jack was muted. I played around with alsamixer settings and now I get some audio from the rear jack. However the volume is very low. The front audio jack volume is normal. I have already disabled auto mute. What did I miss?

[image]

Comment: Related: [How to fix Bang and Olufsen Audio for HP laptops?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/899021/how-to-fix-bang-and-olufsen-audio-for-hp-laptops/945969#945969)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks for pointing me to that post. I will try the suggestions there and post here if any of them works. I did have an HP Envy Desktop with Bang & olufsen stuff in it which has been working for 4 years now without any problems. So I thought maybe this wasn't an issue.