# No sound or low sound from HP laptop top speakers

Tags: sound, alsa, hardware, 22.10, hda-intel

I have an HP Spectre x360 laptop. The only way I can get any sound out of the top speakers (Bang and Olufsen) is to follow the top [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/899021/how-to-fix-bang-and-olufsen-audio-for-hp-laptops/1120269#1120269) to this question. (using HDAJackRetask)

The audio volume is extremely low when I retask pins 0x14 and 0x1e. What can I do to get the volume up? All volume sliders are at max.

Here's a [link to a hwprobe](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=c54afc26b5) of my system.