# HP Victus 16-e0008ur strange squeaking noise when playing audio

Tags: drivers, sound, speakers

My laptop has a strange "trait" when the bios starts up I hear a strange sound, but as soon as the initialization was over it would click off. Today I installed ubuntu and the same sound I hear when booting the pc I now hear every time I play audio. I tried following the instructions in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/899021/how-to-fix-bang-and-olufsen-audio-for-hp-laptops/1120269#1120269), but after this manipulation the sound just stopped playing.

```
OS: Ubuntu 23.10 x86_64 
Host: Victus by HP Laptop 16-e0xxx
Kernel: 6.5.0-9-generic
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 5600H with Radeon G
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon Vega Series / Ra
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile
```

Comment: Could be a capacitor failing,  can you look inside your machine (with the power OFF)?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the knowledge to do that :-/
But even so, why is it that when I use windows there is no sound, but in linux there is.